# How to use classes for Tkinter GUI development in Python

Tags: python, class, tkinter

my goal here is to have a class that creates a form and then using its methods to create all sorts of widgets, simple as that. The problem is, in some cases I have no idea how to pass a widget handle (or anything that links to a specific widget) to a different method. For example here is something I wrote earlier:

```
import tkinter
class CreateForm (tkinter.Tk):
    def __init__(self, form_title, form_icon, form_width, form_height):
        super().__init__()
        self.eval('tk::PlaceWindow . center')
        self.geometry(f'{form_width}x{form_height}')
        self.title(form_title)
        self.iconbitmap(form_icon)    
    def start(self):
        self.mainloop()
    def CreateLabel(self, master, txt, lbl_x, lbl_y):
        tkinter.Label(master=master, text=txt).place(x=lbl_x, y=lbl_y)
    def btn_click(self):
        print('button has been clicked')
    def CreateButton(self, master, txt, btn_x, btn_y):
        tkinter.Button(master=master, text=txt, command=self.btn_click).place(x=btn_x, y=btn_y)
```

Here I simply tried to create a form, then add a label and a button to the form. By clicking the button, a function named "btn_click" will be invoked. However instead of printing "Hello World", I would like the function to print out whatever text my label has.
This is where my confusion comes from, I have no idea how to pass the label handle to this function.
I will appreciate if you could help me solve this problem, and in addition if you guys have any tips on how to improve my class structure here since my ultimate goal is to create a class that can easily be copied and pasted for other tkinter related projects.

Comment: When `CreateLabel()` is executed more than once, then there are multiple labels created.  So which label's text you want to show when `btn_click()` is executed?

Comment: I placed this class in a different module. In my main module I was planning to have some sort of a dynamic list, so I could store each label separately and then pass their respective text to btn_click function. But this is a question for another time, for the moment suppose that I am running CreateLabel method only once.

Comment: Then use an instance variable to store the label reference and use it in `btn_click()`, like the posted answer but you need to split the line `self.l = tkinter.Label(...).place(...)` into two lines: `self.l = tkinter.Label(...)` and `self.l.place(...)`.  Then you can use `self.l` inside `btn_click()`.

Comment: acw1668 thanks a lot, that solved my problem. will you be kind to explain why separating creation and placement of the widget did the trick?

Comment: It is because the return of function `place(...)` is `None`.

Answer (score 0):

```
def CreateLabel(self, master, txt, lbl_x, lbl_y):
    self.l = tkinter.Label(master=master, text=txt).place(x=lbl_x, y=lbl_y)
def btn_click(self):
    print(self.l.cget("text"))
```

See `tkinter.Widget.cget()`
https://docs.python.org/3/library/tkinter.ttk.html#tkinter.ttk.Widget

Comment: Do you notice that `self.l` is None due to issue asked many times in SO?

Comment: Thank you for the answer, however this alteration leads to the following error:
AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'cget'